# Keep Localhost Server app in background until I turn it off

Tags: background-process, web-server

I'm using a Localhost server Android App. Which I use to develop WordPress and writing articles.

But, the problem is it destroys after some times. Because, I've keep this app on background.

When I develop another websites it stays for maximum 5/6m but only best 20s for WordPress.

I'm using Low Ram Config but it isn't working for me.

You see the screenshot here [image]

Device Log

> Symphony Marshmallow 6.0
>
> No Root ( Unable to root)

Comment: Have you excluded it from being Dozed (Android 6's battery saving)?

Comment: @Izzy I notice it works fine while it's on Battery Saving. Because, Saving stops background data and other services and keep the ram free. But, I've tested excluding battery saver. Doesn't work.